# My pandas dataframe is not appending a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to append a pandas data frame with a dictionary. However, its not appending. I am getting an empty dataframe when I print it. Kindly tell me where have made a mistake in my code.

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.DataFrame()

def tstfunc():
    dicts = {'a': "pavan", 'b':"sunder"}
    dfs.append(dicts, ignore_index=True)
    print(dfs)
    
tstfunc()
```

Comment: From the accepted answer: "DataFrame.append is not an in-place operation" -> `dfs = dfs.append(dicts, ignore_index=True)` you might end up with a scoping issue, you'll also need to return the results back rather than printing since there are no inplace append, join, merge, or concatenation operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
def tstfunc():
    dfs = pd.DataFrame()
    dicts = {'a': "pavan", 'b':"sunder"}
    dfs=dfs.append(dicts, ignore_index=True)
    return dfs
    
tstfunc()
```

output when you call `tstfunc()`:

```
    a       b
0   pavan   sunder
```

OR

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame()
def tstfunc():
    dicts = {'a': "pavan", 'b':"sunder"}
    return dfs.append(dicts, ignore_index=True)
    
tstfunc()
```

output when you call `tstfunc()`:

```
    a       b
0   pavan   sunder
```

Comment: getting an error, local variable referenced before assignment

Comment: @Pavan it's working fine on my side..can you restart the kernel(if you are using jupyter) and then again check?

Comment: I solved it.. actually I had to declare it with a keyword global inside a function..anyway thanks for suggestions